# How to get gnome to run /etc/gdm/PostSession/Default when using XRDP w/ VNC

Tags: linux, centos, gnome

I use Microsoft's Remote Desktop Client (`mstsc.exe`) to connect to a linux server with GNOME as my desktop. I've set up `/etc/gdm/PostSession/Default` to execute some steps on cleanup - which works when I'm logged in physically. However, `/etc/gdm/PostSession/Default` is not getting executed when I exit my RDP session.

What triggers `/etc/gdm/PostSession/Default` to execute?

**NOTE"** I'm using CentOS 6.5 with Gnome 2.28.2

Comment: When is `/etc/gdcm/PostSession/Default` running for you when you're logged in physically? When you log out?

Comment: @slm yes, it runs on logout as explained here [link](https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable/configuration.html.en)

Comment: When you exit your RDP session, are you logging out or just exiting? I guess I wouldn't expect the session to end when you disconnect from RDP. The session is still running on the remote server.

Comment: I am logging out, not just closing the session.  I use the CentOS System->Log Out menu option.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been said:

You are not ending your session, you are simply disconnecting. If you want a proper login session you should look into `xdmcp` which is the "native" remote shell.

https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Installation_Guide/s2-trouble-remotex.html

Comment: I _am_ logging out, not simply disconnecting.  xdmcp is not much use to me since I am connecting from Windows.